Opinions regarding UI
Ask Ubuntu and many other stack exchange sites has been here with years without redesigning any UI. I feel like it's time for a change. Any thoughts on this?

Your request is: "I think it's time for many people to spend at least a couple hundred hours each changing how things look, while introducing new bugs, etc., just because I think I'd like a new, unspecified, change in how things look." I don't have to pay for it, so I don't care that I'm asking for at least a few 100k+ dollars of other people's time to be spent. Personally, I'd much rather that time be spent fixing actual issues that have already been identified, rather than just giving a facelift to the sites when there are underlying issues which would be of much greater benefit.

"Any thoughts on this?" they are already lacking resources for designing the rest of site themes, I wonder if redesigning the UI worths their existing resource.

The entire StackExchange network is underpinned by a shared theme system, while a good number of sites feature elaborate customizations on top of the basic theme. If you stir that up, it would involve an incredible amount of work to be carried out, in the entire scope of the network. I don't think there is a way to reduce the scope in some manitainable way. Recently they had renewed the color palettes network-wide (for contrast and accessibility considerations), and the emerging bugs had exposed how non-trivial it is to work with their codebase.

Plus I believe they don't have a budget for such a thing: this is about the financial economics of operating the network, and the emphasis is, the budget is spent on keeping the systems operating and well-usable. Which I believe is totally fair.

Oh, okay thanks.
